# MySQL Joining 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

**I found this same question, followed the steps but still an error.**
I've been searching this for many days.

I have 3 tables

**user**

```
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+
| id | fname                       | lname       |
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+
| 4  | John                        | Menezes     |
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+
```

**group**

```
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+
| group_id | group_name            | created_on  |
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+
| 1        | Facebook friends      | 25/12/2012  |
+----------+-----------------------+-------------+
```

**group_members**

```
+----+-------------+-------------+
| id | user_id     | group_id    |
+----+-------------+-------------+
| 4  | 4           |     1       |
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

I want to get Somewhat like this
**Final Output**

```
+----+--------------+-----------------------+
| fname |  lname    |        groupname      |
+----+--------------+-----------------------+
| John  | Menezes   |     Facebook Friends  |
+----+--------------+-----------------------+
```

I used this query

```
SELECT u.fname, u.lname, g.group_name
FROM user AS u
LEFT JOIN group_members AS gm ON gm.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN group AS g ON g.group_id = gm.group_id
```

But its giving me this error

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group AS g ON g.group_id = gm.group_id LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4**

Also tried this

```
where g.low_limit > 70
and g.high_limt < 120
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are running into is that `group` is a reserved word in mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html. You need to put the table and column names in back ticks <strike>single quotes</strike> for MySQL to interpret the name as a table.

try

```
SELECT `u`.`fname`, `u`.`lname`, `g`.`group_name`
FROM `user` AS `u`
LEFT JOIN `group_members` AS `gm` ON `gm`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
INNER JOIN `group` AS `g` ON `g`.`group_id` = `gm`.`group_id`
```

Edited: Name of character change. Thanks to @adrian

Comment: That's backticks, not single quotes - correct in your code, just not in your explanation.

Comment: ohhh God this was so simple

Comment: Welcome to the life of a programmer.

Comment: I have lost so many times with a field name "like" and "unlike" (like is also reserved…) so my advise now. ALWAYS use `` in you query ;)

Comment: Actually I have to make a website for my college project, developing it in PHP...
I ws trying to find out the errors in this query.. ws Totally confused

Comment: i always use `` but only in this query i din use

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT u.fname, u.lname, g.group_name
FROM user AS u
LEFT JOIN group_members AS gm ON gm.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN group AS g ON g.group_id = gm.id
```